# How do I set up Doctrine 2 with multiple Entity Managers in one Project? (without Symfony/Zend)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php, psr-4, psr-0

## Current Situation

I am using **Doctrine 2** *(without Zend and Symfony)* for accessing **two** different **MySQL databases** in **[my Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C39Sh.png)**.

I tried to create **two EntityManager** for each database one. The two **bootstrap files** are set up to use their own **classes**, which are located in the **src-folders**. They are **reverse engineered** with "orm:convert-mapping --from-database" and "orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations=true" and **validated** by "orm:validate-schema".

But the **bootstrap files** use the same **autoload.php** configuration, which is located in the **vendor-folder**, where **composer** and **Doctrine 2** are installed.

The **composer.json** file is located in the project folder.

Currently only the **last generated Schema** "EntitiesAnlagenAnalyse" **is working**, while the **first generated Schema** "EntitiesPreisAnalyse" is producing an **error**:

> ## PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>
> 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' with message
>   'Class 'Artikel' does not exist' in
>   ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php:96
>
> ## Stack trace:
>
> **#1 ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService.php(41):**
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::nonExistingClass('Artikel')
>
> **#2 ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(281):**
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getParentClasses('Artikel')
>
> **#3 ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(311):**
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses('Artikel')
>
> **#4 ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php(78):**
>   Doctrine\Common\P in
>   ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php
>   on line 96

---

### Picture of the Project Folder

For a detailed look on my Project Structure: [picture of the hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C39Sh.png)

---

## Code

---

### composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0":
      {
        "": ["EntitiesAnlagenAnalyse/src/", "EntitiesPreisAnalyse/src/"]
      }
  }
}
```

### EntitiesAnlagenAnalyse\bootstrap.php

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once(__DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php");

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode, null, null, false);
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__."/proxies");

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'dbname' => '****',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$AnlagenAnalyseManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

### EntitiesPreisAnalyse\bootstrap.php

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once(__DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php");

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode, null, null, false);
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__."/proxies");

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'dbname' => '****',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$PreisAnalyseManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

---

## Update #1

If I try to use the second EntityManager "PreisAnalyse" now, it seems like it is using the mapping of the "EntitiesAnlagenAnalyse", because it tries to get the column "t0.bezeichnung", which is only in the "Artikel" class in "EntitiesAnlagenAnalyse". But it is querying the correct database, where "bezeichnung" is not existing.

**INFO: Some of the classes have the same name in both managers. So there is a Table 'Artikel' in both EntitiyManagers.**

> ## PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException'
>
> with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   't0.bezeichnung' in 'field list'' in
>   ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:104
>
> ## Stack trace:
>
> **#0
>   ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php(104):**
>   PDO->query('SELECT t0.artik...')
>
> **#1
>   ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php(833):**
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->query('SELECT t0.artik...')
>
> **#2
>   ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister.php(884):**
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT t0.artik...', Array,
>   Array)
>
> **#3
>   ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php(181):**
>   Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->loadAll(Array,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL)
>
> **#4
>   ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php(164):**
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository- in ProjectDir\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   on line 71

---

## Update #2

Now I tried to switch the strings in the array of the autoloader PSR-0 and it is working for the "PreisAnalyseManager" and for the "AnlagenAnalyseManger" but only until it reaches a query with the "Artikel" class. So it is definetely a problem with the autoloader and the new question is:

**How can I define namespaces in the autoloader, so doctrine is using it the right way?**

### compose.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0":
      {
        "": ["EntitiesPreisAnalyse/src/", "EntitiesAnlagenAnalyse/src/"]
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: try to create a proper namespace for each directory:
`"autoload": {
    "psr-0":
      {
        "EntitiesPreisAnalyse": "EntitiesPreisAnalyse/src/",
        "EntitiesAnlagenAnalyse": "EntitiesAnlagenAnalyse/src/"
      }
 }`

Comment: i already tried that, but where can i define the namespaces, so doctrine is using it the right way? (ERROR: "Class does not Exist")

Comment: When i use this autoload configuration, then i use in the code: `$artikelRepository = $PreisAnalyseManager -> getRepository('EntitiesPreisAnalyse\Artikel');` but it keeps getting the **ERROR: "Class 'EntitiesPreisAnalyse\Artikel' does not Exist"**

Comment: it is only working if i load it directly: `require_once '../../EntitiesPreisAnalyse/src/Artikel.php';
                    $artikelRepository = $PreisAnalyseManager -> getRepository('Preis\Artikel');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **solution** was to use the **PSR-4** autoloader **instead** of the **PSR-0** and like *sadok-f* said in the comments below my question, I added specific namespaces and came finally to that **composer.json**:

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4":
      {
        "Preis\\": "EntitiesPreisAnalyse/src/",
        "Anlagen\\": "EntitiesAnlagenAnalyse/src/"
      }
  }
}
```